# I lost my project - SourceTree - Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

What happened:

- I made a personal Bitbucket account
- I git init in the project directory
- Opened it in SourceTree and made initial commit
- I realized the commit was made on my other account
- I reversed commit
- Deleted the .git from the project directory
- I git init in the directory
- Opened it in SourceTree
- All my classes are gone, all the layouts
- All I see is a bunch of files (hundreds even thousands of dependencies I was using)

Is my project gone ? I have worked on this for months and it's a personal project.

Comment: Why did you delete .git directory?

Comment: I deleted the .git folder thinking i had to do it to re open it in sourcetree:/

Comment: You said you've used Bitbucket. Did you push your commits to Bitbucket? In that case just clone the repository again (you only might have lost changes which were not pushed yet).

Comment: The sourcetree menu item `reverse commit` does a `git revert` for the consequences see mgarciaisaia answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you did a `git revert` when you say you "reversed" commit, then you modified your working copy so it didn't contain any of the commited files anymore. Those two steps (commiting and reverting the files) were still logged in your git repository (your `.git` directory) - but you deleted it.

The only *git way* to get your files back is if you happened to `git push` your project *before* deleting your `.git` directory. You didn't state anything about this, so it seems you *haven't*, but check your Bitbucket repository to see if it has those two commits in it.

When you deleted your `.git` directory, you erased all the information git has about your repo - so it can't recover anything. If this is the case, the only way to recover your files is from a backup, from your OS's "trash folder" - if it has any -, or doing some file recovery (TimeMachine, testdisk, etc) :/